# Mathjax does not work

Tags: bug, mathjax

In the recent days, MathJax often stops working. This means that, when I view questions with Math formulas (e.g. [Consumer optimum in an economy with a continuum of commodities](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/210/consumer-optimum-in-an-economy-with-a-continuum-of-commodities)), I see dollar-signs instead of math formulas, e.g:

```
$$U = \int_0^1 c_i^\theta\,di\qquad 0<\theta<1$$
```

This happens both in Firefox (40) and Chromium (44), both on Ubuntu 14.04.

Is it only me?

Comment: Sometimes it takes time to load up the MathJax after the basic html has loaded. Do you have to refresh when you see the dollar signs? How long do you wait?

Comment: @KitsuneCavalry I wait a lot of time, I also try to refresh, but nothing helps...

Comment: Then I'm afraid I'm unsure what the problem is. I haven't run into it.

Comment: This problem is likely to affect the entire SE network, so you might find some more help at http://meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Does the problem persist if you disable all add-ons?

Comment: @EnergyNumbers I will check when the problem comes back  (it comes and goes).